# Sorting char pointer using STL sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl

Anyone knows how to sort a `char*` using `std::sort()` STL function? In c++

If i use sort like sort(str.begin(),str.end());. An error is coming -'request for member begin and end in str, which is of non-char type 'char*'.

I know how to sort a string using `std::sort()` in `#include<algorithm>`

Comment: All `std::sort` needs is a "pointer" to the first element, and a "pointer" to one beyond the last element. For a null-terminated byte string it's very easy to get both of these pointers.

Comment: If i use sort like sort(str.begin(),str.end());. An error is coming -'request for member begin and end in str, which is of non-char type 'char*'.

Comment: Note the word *pointer* in my comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a pointer to the beginning of a string, you can pass it directly to `std::sort` as the first parameter.

Then the second parameter needs to be the pointer to *end* of the string. You can get it by adding string length to that pointer.

```
std::sort(ptr, ptr + std::strlen(ptr));
```

Comment: Can you also tell how to implement std::unique() for the same

Comment: @silkynene Just about all algorithm functions deal with *ranges* using a "begin" iterator and an "end" iterator. For a C-style null-terminated string the "begin" iterator is the pointer to the first character, and the "end" iterator is a pointer to the terminator. Using the that information, together with the information from this answer, what does that tell you? How do you think you should call e.g. [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) (which expects basically the same arguments)?

Comment: std::unique(ptr, ptr+std::strlen(ptr)); but how to return this?

Comment: @silkynene It will return a pointer, so `char *new_end = std::unique(...);`. The new string size is then `new_end - ptr`. You might also want to insert a null-terminator at the new end (`*new_end = '\0';`).

Comment: How to return this value?

Comment: @Priyank That's worthy of a separate question. But if that string is passed as a parameter, and you modify it in place, then you don't need to "return" it in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort char* strings, but you can't modify string literals, so you need to have the string as a char array to be able to modify it (including sort):

```
//this is a string literal that can't be modified
const char* string_literal = "this can't be modified";

// this is a char[] that is initialized from a string literal
char str1[] = { "can modify" };
//array can be converted to pointer to first element
char* str_ptr = str1;
//str1 can be directly passed to sort, i just added str_ptr to make the conversion explicit
std::sort(str_ptr, str_ptr + std::strlen(str_ptr));

//the method with std::begin only works for char[], doesn't work for char*
//this could be initialized with a string literal as in previous example
char str2[] = { 'c', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'm', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'f', 'y', '\0' };

//end -1 because we want to keep the last character in place (the end string null termination character)
std::sort(std::begin(str2), std::end(str2) - 1);
```